# Ubuntu 16.04 switching GPU in MacBookPro11,3

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, gpu, macbook-pro, nvidia-prime

I'm using ubuntu in dual boot with macOS sierra on MacBookPro11,3 (mid 2014). When I use ubuntu it always use the nvidia graphic card instead of the integrated intel GPU. I need to know how to switch the GPU. I've already tried those methods:

- [Bumblebee](http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Hardware/Video/GraficaIbrida/NvidiaOptimus/Bumblebee):
  If I use it, the user interface become unusable because I cannot scale the interface and it is very very small with the retina display.
- prime-select intel: I've tried with the prime-select command but when I reboot the system it switches again in the nvidia mode.
- prime GUI: I tied also with the GUI of the nvidia drivers but there is no Prime select tab.